# Login to website using urllib2 -- Python 2.7

Tags: python, html

I need to log into this site: http://snowstresser.com/members/login.php
It has no post action, so I don't know what to do...

I realise that different websites use different login forms etc. So how do I figure out how to optimise it for each website? I'm assuming I need to look for something in the html file but no idea what.

I do NOT want to use Mechanize or any other library (which is what all the other answers are about on here and don't actually help me to learn what is happening), as I want to learn by myself how exactly it all works.

The urllib2 documentation really isn't helping me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Click the login button with fake user/password. It will forward to another page. View the source of that page and you'll find your required POST things. These things are very easy to catch using firebug plugin of firefox browser.

Below is an example code that can be handy to perform the POST operation. But still, the requests or mechanize will be better choice as per my observation.

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, param)
req.add_header('Referer', referer)
req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')    
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = res.read()
res.close()
```